# Loading .xls file with Pig Latin

Tags: excel, apache-pig, hortonworks-sandbox

I have a .xls file with thousand rows with the following structure :

```
id   | number | date   | description

1232 | 41515  | 3/9/16 | amazing
```

I'm trying to load it skipping the first header row and **without date column** (so just id, number, description and I haven't found yet how to) using Pig with the following script :

```
REGISTER /usr/hdp/current/pig-client/lib/piggybank.jar
data = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/file.xls' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'NOCHANGE', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER') 
as (Id:chararray,case_number:chararray,date:chararray,block:chararray,iucr:chararray);
data_sample = LIMIT data 10;
DUMP data_sample;
```

but I'm getting a weird result from the dump with lines such as :

```
( � � � � � �,,,,)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way of loading .xls files into hdfs using csvexcelstorage.You will have to save the .xls file as .csv file and then use csvexcelstorage to load it.

Also note that you have 4 fields and your schema has 5 fields.

```
data = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/file.csv' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'NOCHANGE', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER') as (Id:chararray,case_number:chararray,date:chararray,desc:chararray);
data_sample = LIMIT data 10;
DUMP data_sample;
```

Comment: I mentionned that I would like to get all columns beside date and didn't know how to

Comment: You cannot exlude columns in LOAD.If you don't want to include a column, then in your second statement generate the needed columns like this data_sample = FOREACH data GENERATE Id,case_number,desc;

Comment: Somehow the data returned has a structure such as : (col1;col2;col3;etc), it seems like the "AS" part doesn't do anything, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I found the problem, I was opening the CSV with Excel and it was only showing the data, the structure was misleading, I opened it with Notepad and I could now see that the columns were in fact delimited by ";" and not ",", everything is working fine now, thanks a lot !